# ArcPy Cursor Where Clause to Delete Rows -- why is if statement needed?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am writing a function to delete rows based on a certain value. The first code block below doesn't work; the second code block does work. I don't understand why I have to add the "if" clause to get it to work. Isn't the point of having a where clause (my `sql` variable) to select only the fields and rows that meet that condition?

**Doesn't work, curious why?**

```
def delRows(shp_in, fieldname, Val):
    """
    Delete rows based on values in specific fields
    :shp_in:            input shapefile for which rows are to be deleted
    :fieldname:         fieldname for finding value to delete
    :Val:               trigger value for row deletion
    """
    import arcpy
    sql = "'" + fieldname + "' = " + "'" + str(Val) + "'"
    print sql
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp_in, [fieldname], sql) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

#

**Does work**

```
def delRows(shp_in, fieldname, Val):
    """
    Delete rows based on values in specific fields
    :shp_in:            input shapefile for which rows are to be deleted
    :fieldname:         fieldname for finding value to delete
    :Val:               trigger value for row deletion
    """
    import arcpy
    sql = "'" + fieldname + "' = " + "'" + str(Val) + "'"
    print sql
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp_in, [fieldname], sql) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == Val:
                cursor.deleteRow()
```

#

**Edit**
Here's the print-out of the sql statement as coded in both of the above:

```
'Site' = '0'
```

#

Comment: could you show the content of the `sql` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQL query is likely wrong and all rows are returned, so the `if` check actually do the filtering.

In the SQL query, the field name should not be quoted.
Also if the value if numeric, it should also not be quoted. This [doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm) gives more details.

```
sql = fieldname + " = " + str(delVal)
```

Comment: I changed it to: sql = fieldname + " = " + "'" + str(delVal) + "'"

Comment: print out is: Site = '0' RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used.

Comment: if it is a numerical field, the value should also not be quoted (see the [doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm))

Comment: I tried: sql = fieldname + " = " + delVal

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: sql = fieldname + " = " + str(delVal)